# WordPress Importer Call to undefined function set_time_limit()

Tags: php, functions

I am trying to import my media library via the wordpress importer, but I keep running into this error, which seemingly lacks an explanation:

[image]

```
root@test:~# grep -R "max_execution_time" /etc/php/8.1/
/etc/php/8.1/cgi/php.ini:max_execution_time = 900
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini:max_execution_time = 900
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/1648278293221077.conf:php_value[max_execution_time] = 900
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf:; be killed. This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option
/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/166643563141647.conf:php_value[max_execution_time] = 900
/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini:max_execution_time = 900
/etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini:max_execution_time = 900

Also, my `wp-config.php` has `ini_set ( 'max_execution_time', 900);`

So at this point, I am confused...  Anyone have any ideas?
```

Comment: Have you tried downgrading from php 8.1 to 7.4?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast, you nailed it... downgrading to 7.4 got rid of error message... but my media imports still failed :-/  different problem... but thanks for the progress...

Comment: If anyone else has trouble with the wordpress importer... try this plugin... worked perfectly for me...  https://wordpress.org/plugins/moving-media-library/